# Логи от Django в Gitlab

Tags: django, docker, ci-cd, graylog

Есть полноценный проект на Django, который размещается через Docker, используется Gitlab CI/CD, также подключен Graylog. Не выполняется одна операция внутри Django связанная с базой данных, я хотел бы найти логи и посмотреть, почему не выполняется. Доступов к серверам нет, есть доступ к Graylog, но как я понимаю, там показывает только логи от Docker, а не Django проекта. Где их возможно найти, логи от Django?

Судя по файлу настрока Django, есть Sentry, но отдельного url для него не нашел

```
LOGGING = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": True,
    "formatters": {
        "verbose": {
            "format": "%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(process)d %(module)s %(message)s"
        },
        "simple": {"format": "%(levelname)s %(message)s"},
    },
    "handlers": {
        "file": {
            "level": "INFO",
            "class": "logging.FileHandler",
            "filename": path_to_log_file,
            "formatter": "verbose",
        },
        "console": {
            "level": "INFO",
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "formatter": "verbose",
        },
    },
    "loggers": {
        "django": {"handlers": ["file"], "propagate": True, "level": "WARNING"},
        "django.request": {"handlers": ["file"], "level": "ERROR", "propagate": True},
        "django.db.backends": {"handlers": ["console"], "level": "WARNING"},
        "apps": {"handlers": ["file", "console"], "level": "INFO"},
    },
}

# Sentry
raven_dsn = ENV_DICT.get("RAVEN_DSN", False)
if raven_dsn:
    INSTALLED_APPS.append("raven.contrib.django.raven_compat")
    RAVEN_CONFIG = {"dsn": raven_dsn, "environment": ENVIRONMENT}
    LOGGING["root"] = {"level": "WARNING", "handlers": ["sentry"]}
    LOGGING["handlers"]["sentry"] = {  # type: ignore
        "level": "ERROR",
        "class": "raven.contrib.django.raven_compat.handlers.SentryHandler",
        "tags": {"environment": ENVIRONMENT},
    }

    for logger in ["django", "django.request", "django.db.backends", "apps"]:
        if logger in LOGGING["loggers"]:  # type: ignore
            LOGGING["loggers"][logger]["handlers"].append("sentry")  # type: ignore

    LOGGING["loggers"].update(  # type: ignore
        {
            "raven": {
                "level": "DEBUG",
                "handlers": ["console", "file"],
                "propagate": False,
            },
            "sentry.errors": {
                "level": "DEBUG",
                "handlers": ["console", "file"],
                "propagate": False,
            },
        }
    )
    MIDDLEWARE.append(
        "raven.contrib.django.raven_compat.middleware.SentryResponseErrorIdMiddleware"
    )
```

Comment: В таком виде на вопрос не ответить - недостаточно информации. Graylog просто инструмент, в зависимости от его настроек он может собирать разные логи. Далее не ясно, что значит "логи от докер". Куда джанго пишет логи и пишет ли зависит от настроек и от того как вы запускаете приложение (начиная от настроек logging модуля питона, а они могут переопределяться например gunicorn-ом, если вы его используете).

Comment: Приложил код из файла настроек. А чтобы узнать, насчет unicorn, нужно смотреть в Docker файл?